# What jQuery mobile build is running at http://jquerymobile.com/test?

Tags: jquery-mobile

It seems that the jQuery Mobile test site at http://jquerymobile.com/test is not really running alpha 2 (despite of what is written on the first page).

It definitely shows different (and perhaps less?) bugs than the alpha 2 demo at  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/

Does that mean that the test site is running the latest nightly build? If not, what version is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I just found out it is the daily build of jQuery Mobile. Which (as I hoped) makes it the easiest way to stay up to date with the latest development version.

Answer (score 0):

if you view source on the page. and then click the link to the 'js' file (script src="js/" ) this then links to here.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/

v 1.4.4?

edit: it looks like the mobile script may be combined with the jQuery script.

search for * jQuery Mobile Framework : widget factory extentions for mobile  in the js and that may be the start of it.

cant see a version number though :(

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant the jquery mobile build. I also had a look at the source code, but the jquery mobile version does not seem to be noted there.

Comment: Ah having another look in the script... most of the way through the script seems to be some Jquery mobile functions. perhaps they combined the scripts. if you search for: * jQuery Mobile Framework : widget factory extentions for mobile      then you should find the start of the mobile stuff

Comment: Thanks, but I knew all this already... I've done exactly the same thing as you. The reason I asked this question is that I was hoping to get an answer from some jQuery Mobile insider. I wasn't too lucky in getting any answers on the jQuery forums...